# Apache not proxing node application

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

I have a node application running on port 8888 and configured Apache as it's reverse proxy. But it is not proxing it. I have a .net core app running successfully which also has Apache as reverse proxy. Curling localhost:8888 is giving the response, means node app is responding. I have centos 7 installed on my VPS.

Below is my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    ServerName t.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.t.domain.com
    ErrorLog /home/dotNetCoreApps/logs/tew-error.log
    CustomLog /home/dotNetCoreApps/logs/tew-access.log common
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =t.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.t.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The SSL redirection directives were causing the problem. After removing those lines The website was loading successfully. I don't know why, but if anyone knows then please post the answer. Right now for SSL I'm using cloudflare flexible SSL and not full, but latter is expected.